# How can I still use Borderlayout constant with a panel that is not a different Layout manager?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, border-layout

How am I able to use `Borderlayout.EAST` on a panel for this particular case with a panel that has a different layout, which is a `BoxLayout` layout manager? Don't the panel itself has to be able a `BorderLayout` manager in order for it to be able to use `BorderLayout.CONSTANT`?

```
 JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
 jp1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
 JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
 jp1.add(jp2, BorderLayout.EAST); //This worked even though jp1 is a BoxLayout, how did it use BorderLayout?
```

Comment: BorderLayout.EAST is just a constant, that is supported by the Component.add method

Comment: What makes you think it _"works"_? Do you mean why does it compile? Please define _"worked"_

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, how does it compile?

Comment: It will compile, because [`Container.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) allows for (Component, Object). Does that mean that the constraint will be used in this case? No. That's why I asked why you think it _"works"_. It will compile, but you will not see the `BorderLayout.EAST` effect as you would if the layout was set to `BorderLayout`. tashgods answer explains more.

Comment: Same thing for `GridBagLayout`. When using this layout, you specify `GridBagConstraints` as the second `Object` argument. for the _same_ `add` method, that every `Container` has. But it will only work if the layout manager is set to `GridBagLayout`. You could add (and compile) your example passing a `GridBagConstraints` as the second argument, but that doesn't mean the constraints will take effect

Answer (score 3):

This can be a little convoluted. When you `add()` a `Component` to a `Container`, [`addImpl()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addImpl-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-int-) handles the request. An original `LayoutManager` like `BorderLayout` understands constants like [`BorderLayout.EAST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST), which has the `String` value `"East"`. A newer `LayoutManager2` like [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) never sees the unused constraint. In particular,

> If the current layout manager implements `LayoutManager2`, then `LayoutManager2.addLayoutComponent(Component,Object)` is invoked on it. If the current layout manager does not implement `LayoutManager2`, and `constraints` is a `String`, then `LayoutManager.addLayoutComponent(String,Component)` is invoked on it.

Addendum: [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) implements both `LayoutManager` and `LayoutManager2`. Although `BoxLayout` must provide both variations of `addLayoutComponent()`,  the method is "Not used by this class." In effect, the `BorderLayout.EAST` constraint is ignored.

```
void    addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints)
        Not used by this class.
void    addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp)
        Not used by this class.
```

Comment: Still confused... would it be possible for you to explain easier?

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you help me out please?

Comment: @OM It's not really proper in this SO format to try and _"summon"_ someone that is not part of the original discussion.

Comment: @OM: I'm not sure where you are having trouble, but I've elaborated above.